# Locust.io signal success or failure without an HTTP Call

Tags: locust, stress-testing

I'm making a standard database call using an SDK, so there isn't an HTTP request. Depending on the result of the request (generally just exception or success) I would like to trigger a success or failure so that it is logged in the UI.

The events.response_success.fire and events.response_failure.fire that I've seen on some websites aren't listed in the [documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#event-hooks) for locust under event hooks, so I'm assuming they're deprecated.

Is there another way of manually triggering a success or failure of a request?

Current code (somewhat generalized):

```
   @task(100)
    def read_item(self) -> None:
        (
            database_to_read,
            attribute_to_read,
            key_to_read,
        ) = self.sdk[database_to_read].read_data(
                conditions={condition_id: key_to_read}
            )
            # Trigger success here
```

The workaround that I've found is to use an HTTP user, make a dummy call, catch the response and then run the code that I want, but this feels like a hack.

Example:

```
with self.client.get("/", catch_response=True) as response:
            try:
                (
                    database_to_read,
                    attribute_to_read,
                    key_to_read,
                ) = 
                    self.sdk[database_to_read].read_data(
                        conditions={condition_id: key_to_read}
                    )
                response.success()
            except Exception as e:
                response.failure(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Locust docs has a section on [Testing other systems/protocols](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) that covers this. Specifically, what you'd be looking for is the request [event](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#events). Example:

```
    self.environment.events.request.fire(
        request_type="grpc",
        name=call_details.method,
        response_time=(time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000,
        response_length=response_length,
        response=response,
        context=None,
        exception=exception,
    )
```

Comment: And this will trigger a failure if there's an exception or a success if there's no exception?

Comment: Yes. No exception is a success. If there is an exception, it's a failure.

Comment: Sorry, took a little to come back to it. That worked, thank you!