# Is there a way to get stats for task executed if I am using Locust User class ( like locust HttpUser class provides all stats)

Tags: python-3.x, locust

How to get the summary of task executed when we use Loucst User class

locust 2.15.1

I am using Locust to generate traffic.

I want the summary of like how many times it passed/failed

```
from locust import User, task, events 

class TestsPortalAuthentication(User):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     user_list = [
        "user2@prabh2-0.ca"

    ]

    def get_user(self):
        return random.choice(self.user_list)

     @task(1)
    def portal_auth(self):
        user = self.get_user()
        print(f"user selected is {user}")
        start_time = time.time()
        app = OneIDApplication(pseudo_domain='prabh2',
                               cloud_name='zslogin.net',
                               admin_password='xxx',
                               admin_name=user)
        success, auth_res = app.auth_collection.portal_authentication(user=user, usecache=False,
                                                                      want_response=True)
        assert success
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locust.io signal success or failure without an HTTP Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534614/locust-io-signal-success-or-failure-without-an-http-call)